# Read json field with accents - javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have some problem with the following json file :

```
{
    "foo supé": 10                  
}
```

I try to read the field "foo supé" and then to log it into the console with the following code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

</div>

<script charset="utf-8">

var app =angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http){ 
    $http.get('./data.json').success(function(json) {
        console.log(json["foo supé"]);
    });
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

In the console, I get an "undefined" when I read the value and if I remove the accent, it's working. How I can fix this ?

Comment: Try looping through each property to see if the JSON was parsed incorrectly: `for(var i in json){ console.log('%s: %s', i, json[i]) }`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried escaping it with `\` ?

Comment: Yes and it's changes nothing.

Comment: You have escaped it where? In the JSON itself or in the AngularJS call of the JSON?

Comment: You can also \u UTF-8 character code(full list here http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm ), so your é would become \uc3a9

Comment: I escaped in the AngularJs call of the JSON.

Comment: If you were to escape only one of them, it should have been the JSON itself. Try escaping both ones

Comment: And again, you can use UTF-8 codes, you can even do it automatically(write a simple function that replaces special characters with their UTF-8 equivalent)